# python: append only specific elements from a list

Tags: python

i have a list of a list:

```
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

i have a list:

```
row = [1,2,3]
```

how do i append to `b` only `row[0]` and `'3847'` and `row[2]` such that `b` will equal:

```
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3847,3]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to be more specific.

This will accomplish what you want:

```
b.append([row[0], 3847, row[2]])
```

But isn't really a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.append([ x if x != 2 else 3847 for x in row])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b + [[row[0],3847,row[2]]]
```

Comment: I think you mean, `b + [[row[0], 3242, row[2]]]`

Comment: To append the data they'd need `b = b + [[row[0],3847,row[2]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

`b + [row[0],3847,row[2]]` would give you:

```
>>> b + [row[0],3847,row[2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 1, 3847, 3]
```

In order to get `b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,3847,3]]`, you need to use `append` as suggested by "Nick Presta". You may have received other suitable solutions if you made the problem statement clearer.